# jsp out.write scriptlet tag within scriptlet

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

how do i out.write scriptlet tag when the out.write is already in scriptlet tag?

```
    <% if (answerList.size() > 2){
                            int toPrint = answerList.size() - 2;
                            int init = 2;

                            for (int x = 0; x < toPrint; x++){
                                out.write("<td width='30%' class='label' nowrap='nowrap'><label></label></td>");
                                out.write("<td><input type='checkbox' name='to_delete" + (init+1) + "' id='to_delete" + (init+1) + "' value='to_delete'> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp ");
                                out.write("<input type='text' name='answer' id='answer' class='mlselect'  maxlength='200' size='90' value='<%=((SurveyAnswerBean)answerList.get(answerList.size()-"+(init+1) +")).getAnswerText()%>'> &nbsp ");
                             }
                            System.out.println("Answer List more than 2"); 
                            System.out.println("To print: " + toPrint);
                        }%>
```

i have tried but it has tag error, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you **cannot** nest scriplets tags, and it also doesn't make sense to do it (becuase you can't evaluate server-side variables on the client-side).

You should replace:

```
"...value='<%=((SurveyAnswerBean)answerList.get(answerList.size()-"+(init+1) +")).getAnswerText()%>'...
```

with:

```
"...value='" + ((SurveyAnswerBean)answerList.get(answerList.size()-(init+1))).getAnswerText() +"'...
```